# Rss to Json Api Android Studio

Tags: android, json, rss, feed

I'm working on an Android studio project and till now I have successfully added some json feeds in my app.
However , i need to add one rss feed also to my app.
The easiest solution to me is to make an online conversion of the rss feed to json feed so I can parse my data with the previous code.
Google API is going to stop by 15th Dec 16' and yahoo query is down .
What would you suggest?
I'm about 5 hours now , trying to find a solution.
*I tried rss2json.com however after the first time fetching the data , the feed is refreshed after a long , very long time.

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please explain what you tried...**add some code**, show examples and explain the problem. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for learn how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own toJson(xml) method and use [XmlPullParser](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) to read and retrieve the data you need to create a new Json object. I'm guessing you want to use your Json parser instead, but at this point you already have the data that you would be using for your application.  So, just use an XML parser instead =).